# Tensorflow Word2Vec KNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does anyone have any advice on creating a Tensorflow/Word2Vec KNN program.

I hope to train on two lists of words, and then receive feedback on which list the inputted word is most likely to fall under.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec ...

By KNN you mean doing a K-Nearest Neighbour on the word vecs? Try a cosine distance for a metric of similarity.

If you don't actually want to do any hard work then just use [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html). They wrap-up a whole load of useful text analysis algorithms.